# c# entity framework with virtual property query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have this class:

```
    public class Message
    {
        public Message()
        {
            Contacts = new List<Contact>();
        }

        public Message(string Sub_Message, string Body_Message, string Date_Send_Message)
        {
            Contacts = new List<Contact>();

            Subject = Sub_Message;
            Body = Body_Message;
            Date = Date_Send_Message;
        }

        public int MessageId { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        public string Date { get; set; }

        public string Body { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to get the table of the Contact, because of that Messages is virtual and all the lazy loading stuff,

This call didn't work to me and got this error:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used
>   for operations that require a connection. in Reference Table

syntax:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Model.Message> LoadMessages()
    {
      using (db) {
       var x = from qr in db.Messages
                            order by qr.Subject
                            select qr;
          }
     }
```

While this works:

```
public ObservableCollection<Model.Message> LoadMessages()
{
    using (db)
    {
        var Messages = db.Messages.Include(z => z.Contacts).ToList();

        return new ObservableCollection<Model.Message>(Messages); 
    }
}
```

So I am using the queries inside a service called MessageService, Everytime I want to use the dbContext I create a function for it and put it inside using(db)

Like this:

```
     public class MessageService
        {
            ReadingFromData db = new ReadingFromData();
            public ObservableCollection<Model.Message> LoadMessages()
            {
                using (db)
                {
                    //Do something with db
                }
            }
}
```

Also, can someone explain to me how this works, and how to work with entity framework queries correct

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some code to show how are you using the context. If the connection is closed, lazy loading will not work.

Comment: edited the post @Harsh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should understand that this code does not query database:

```
var x = from qr in db.Messages
        orderby qr.Subject
        select qr;
```

it's just a query definition (expression) which should be translated into SQL and sent to the database server *when* you'll execute it. Executing is enumerating query results, or using one of LINQ operators with immediate execution type (see [Classification of Standard Query Operators by Manner of Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution)). I.e. when later in the code you'll enumerate `x` or if you'll try to store query results in a list, it is possible that database context `db` will be already disposed. And of course, you will get an error

```
var x = db.Messages; // query is not executed
db.Dispose(); // context disposed
foreach(var m in x) // exception here, you try to execute query which uses disposed context
   ...
```

Now about lazy-loading. It works by storing database context in the proxy entities which inherit from your entities. So actually `db.Messages` will return entities of some type `MessageWithDbContext` with `db` value stored internally. It is required for making additional 'lazy' database queries *later*. And again, if at that point of time database context is disposed, then you'll get an exception:

```
 var x = db.Messages.ToList(); // query is executed, messages are loaded
 db.Dispose();  // context disposed
 foreach(var m in x)
    m.Contacts.Count(); // exception - you try to execute contacts query with disposed db
```

How to solve this issue? Either make sure that database context is not disposed while you are working with the query and making additional 'lazy' calls. Or use *eager loading* as you are doing in the second example. Eager loading allows you to load related entities when you are executing the query:

```
 // both messages and contacts are loaded from database when you execute the query
 var x = db.Message.Include(m => m.Contacts).ToList();
 db.Dispose();
 foreach(var m in x)
    m.Contacts.Count();
```

In this case no additional 'lazy' calls are required, so you can dispose database context and work with query results.

Comment: So eager loading get the result instantly instead of waiting until execution?

Comment: @Zakk eager loading will get related entities without waiting until you need them. Query itself can be deferred if you will not execute it e.g. with `ToList()` call (see the first example)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy One question mate, why everybody uses `public virtual ICollection` when they want to hold a collection in a class, why it is not simply `public List<SomeClass> myList` ?

Answer (score 2):

Lazy loading will work only if the property is accessed while the connection to the context is open (or not disposed).

```
            using (db)
            {
                //If you try to load the data here, lazy loading will work.
            }
```

Now, when you use include, EF does eager loading and gets the related data for you. That is why your data is available when you are using include.

```
var Messages = db.Messages.Include(z => z.Contacts).ToList();
```